# SQLITE multiple files

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

Sorry about this unprofessional question but I'm kinda new to sqlite but I was wondering if there's any way I can open two files in same python command         `db = sqlite3.connect('./cogs/database/users.sqlite')`
when I open this in my command it doesn't allow me to do same thing in the same command to open another file so for example
open         `db = sqlite3.connect('./cogs/database/users.sqlite')` and read something from it if so
open         `db = sqlite3.connect('./cogs/database/anotherfile.sqlite')` and insert to it
but it always accepts first file only and ignore second file

Comment: Try to add commas and periods to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `db1` so it connects to users.sqlite,
and `db2` so it connects to anotherfile.sqlite.

Then you can e.g. SELECT from one
and INSERT into the other,
with a temp var bridging the two.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite databases are single file based, so no - sqlite3.connect builds a connection object to a single data base file.

Even if you build two connection objects, you can't execute queries across them.

If you really need the data from two files at a time you need to merge that data into one data - or don't use sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute queries across two SQLite files, but you will need to execute an ATTACH command on the first connection cursor.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("users.sqlite")
cur = conn.cursor()
cmd = "ATTACH DATABASE 'anotherfile.sqlite' AS otra"
try:
    cur.execute(cmd)

    query = """
       SELECT
           t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.Address
         FROM personnel t1
         LEFT JOIN otra.location t2
           ON t2.PersonId = t1.Id
         WHERE t1.Status = 'current'
         ORDER BY t1.Name;
            """
     cur.execute(query)
     rows = cur.fetchall()
 except sqlite3.Error as err:
     do_something_with(err)
```